# How to : " Change QPoint position to QpointF "

Tags: python, pyqt

I would like to change `QPoint` type into `QpointF`
but I can just see example "QpointF to Qpoint"

```
point = QtCore.QPoint(100.2, 144.23)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use directly the `QPointF` class: `point = QtCore.QPointF(100.2, 144.23)`.

If you already have a `QPoint` want to convert it into a `QPointF`:

```
yourQPoint = QtCore.QPoint(12, 14)
point = QtCore.QPointF(yourQPoint)
```